# Is there a function that returns the integer and decimal part in Rust?

Tags: rust, integer

Is there a function that returns the integer part, a function that returns the number of digits in the integer part, and a function that returns the decimal part of a real number in the Rust language?

I intend to use a function that returns the integer part of a real number, the number of digits in the integer part, and the decimal part of that number.

Comment: The number of digits in the integral part is just `ceiling(log10(abs(n))) + 1`.

Comment: Exists a Function that return the integer and decimal part for the real number in the Rust?

Comment: That depends on which part you want to carry the negative sign if the number is negative. It's also worth noting that the documentation on `f32` and `f64` lists a ton of functions that can do things like this.

Answer (score 1):

Both `f32` and `f64` have methods called [`trunc()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.f32.html#method.trunc) and [`fract()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.f32.html#method.fract) that return the integer and decimal part respectively.

For obtaining the count of digits in the integer part specifically, I recommend obtaining the string representation of the integer part and returning the length of that string:

```rust
fn count_digits_in_integer(value: f32) -> usize {
    let integer_part = value.trunc();
    let digits = integer_part.abs().to_string();
    digits.len()
}
```

Note that we use the absolute value of the `integer_part` so that we do not count any `-` characters.

Comment: This is an extremely inefficient way to count digits.